# testing sql database connection on a firefox extension

Tags: php, html, sql, firefox

currently creating a firefox extension and wanted to receive data from a database I've set up. I've successfully gotten results using a hosted HTML page but was wondering if there was a way to get the same results on my local/unsigned firefox extension?

Comment: Your Firefox extension "hosts" static files, HTML, CSS and JS. You cannot connect to a Database directly using Javascript in this context. Try setting up a Server where you connect to the database and communicate to this server via some sort of API. Good Luck!

Comment: @CloutHack thank you for your help! I've been able to figure out a workaround :)